# matlab copy one array and propagate into many arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, copy

Let's say I have a <100 x 100 double> and I would like to copy (1:100,100) or rows 1 to 100 on column 100. Then I would like to create a new variable x and propagate that n times?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "propagate", but perhaps this is what you're after?

```
x = repmat(arr(:,end), n, 1);
```

(where `arr` is the original array.)